# Intuition about $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

When we first study limits in introductory calculus we get the intuition that
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)= L$$ means as x approaches c, the values of f(x) approaches L.

However in real analysis course, while learning the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits, we express the meaning of the above expression as,

> for values of f(x) in a certain neighbourhood of L, the preimages of f(x) i.e., x lies in a certain neighbourhood of c.

Which in other words means as f(x) approaches L the preimage approaches c. So why is this definition counterintuitive? Are there any other alternative definitions?

Comment: Any reasonable definition of continuity tries to capture the notion: a small change in the input results in a small change in the output. There are several ways of formalizing this.

Comment: I think a geometric intuition is much better than a verbal one in this case. My personal image is not with a standard graph drawing, but with domain and codomain separate blobs and the function as a collection of arrows.

Comment: You can think of continuity in a topological sense too. Topologies are an extra bit of "structure" attached to a set, in the case of ${\mathbb{R}}$, the "structure" uses open intervals as a basis. Continuous functions are those that "preserve" the topological structure in a certain sense (the preimage of open sets should be some open set). In this case, we have the preimage of some ${\epsilon}$ interval around the limit point should give you some ${\delta}$ interval around the input point

Comment: The definition you give is unintuitive if you consider neighbourhood meaning nearby. A better phrasing may be "If x lies close enough to c then f(x) will be as close as we desire to L". Notice this is untrue in the converse "If f(x) is close enough to L then x may not be as close as desired to c"

Comment: Your condition "for values of $f(x)$ in a certain neighbourhood of $L$, the preimages of $f(x)$ i.e., $x$ lies in a certain neighbourhood of $c$" does **not** describe $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)= L$. The correct condition is "the values of $f(x)$ are in a certain neighbourhood of $L$ provided $x$ lies in a certain neighbourhood of $c$".

Comment: Your definition based on preimages is not correct. The right version says that for every neighborhood $B$ of $L$ there is another corresponding deleted neighborhood $A$ of $c$ such that $f(A) \subseteq B$. The notion of preimages does not come into picture. Informally we can control the values of $f(x) $ to lie as near to $L$ as we please by constraining the values of $x$ sufficiently near to $c$.